# Is there a way to change the active color in a treemap from highcharter in r

Tags: r, treemap, r-highcharter

Is there a way to change the color of the active section of the treemap in highcharter when the mouse is hovering over a section that can be drilled down?
I can't seem to find the proper command.

```
hctreemap2(data = M,
           group_vars = c("Order", "Family","Species"),
           size_var = "n",
           color_var = "n",
           layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
           levelIsConstant = FALSE,
           levels = list(
             list(level = 1, dataLabels = list(enabled = F)),
             list(level = 2, dataLabels = list(enabled = F)),
             list(level = 3, dataLabels = list(enabled = T))
           )) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[4],
               maxColor = brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[6]) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>
             Number Measured: {point.value:,.0f}")
```

Thank you in advance.